# Russell's paradox with bounded comprehension

Tags: elementary-set-theory, paradoxes

Consider the set $S = \{A, \varnothing\}$ and define $A = \{x \in S|x \not\in x\}$; this is the same as Russell's paradox except with bounded comprehension, ie $A\in A\iff A\not\in A$.

I think the problem lies in the fact that the composition of $S$ depends on $A$, but the composition of $A$ depends on $S$. My question is: what about the Axiom of Separation (or the other axioms) precludes this construction?

NB: I haven't studied set theory except for reading a little bit in some introductory books in my own time.

Comment: Or consider the set $S=\{\emptyset\}$ and define $A=\{x\in S:x\in B\}$ and $B=\{x\in S:x\notin A\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition is circular. You define $S$ using $A$, and you define $A$ using $S$.

And that's what precludes the definition in this case.

Comment: For those looking for an axiom, try Regularity:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#For_every_two_sets.2C_only_one_can_be_an_element_of_the_other

Comment: Eric, I don't quite get your comment here.

Comment: Just expanding on your answer.  I've noticed a tendency for set theory questioners to demand an axiomatic response.

Comment: This has little to do with axioms; this is about the fact that the definition is circular. And just because we can write something on paper doesn't mean it has any actual content.

Comment: There is the related question of what prevents a set  from having its "local Russel class" as one of its members, which *is* a sensible question. And one that has been answered several times even in my short time on m.se.

Comment: @EricTowers Yeah, I was looking for an axiomatic answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry if this is a silly question, but why don't we allow circular definitions? Eg what's wrong with saying let S = {S} (apart from that it contradicts the axiom of regularity, I think).

Comment: @thedoctar: First of all, this is not a definition for $S$; and it is consistent with the failure of the axiom of regularity that $S=\{S\}$ does exist. In the case of $S=\{A,\varnothing\}$, you are already given $A$ as an element of $S$, you can't define it *again* and expect that $S$ will be consistent with this definition. And there is the circularity, by the redefinition of $A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But isn't $A$ arbitrary? Can't we set it to be whatever we want? Eg if we were to just set $A$ to be $S$, then everything would be fine, we would just have $S = \{S,\varnothing\}$ (ignoring the axiom of regularity). We are free to define $A$, so why can't we define it as a comprehension of $S$ (there would be plenty of comprehensions that wouldn't yield a contradiction)?

Comment: @thedoctar: You can't say "Hey, $A$ is arbitrary, but also $A=\{x\in S\mid x\notin x\}$. That doesn't work like that. If you have that $S=\{S,\varnothing\}$ and you define $A$ as above, then yes you can define $A$ and you will get that $A\notin A$ because $A\notin S$, and $A\subseteq S$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, but I still don't understand why ,if $A$ is arbitrary, we can't set it to be anything we wish using the axioms. You say it doesn't work like that, so I'm asking why?

Also, what I was saying before is that we can define $A$ based on $S$ and not get a contradiction. Ie, we can define $S = \{A,\varnothing\}$ and if we define $A = \{x\in S\}$, in other words $A=S$, then both $S$ and $A$ (which is just $S$ now) don't produce contradictions ignoring the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @thedoctar: Because saying that something is arbitrary you effectively disallow yourself from giving any specific properties. That's like saying "Let $n$ be an arbitrary natural number, since $n$ is even ..." that just doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15422/discussion-between-thedoctar-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: @thedoctar: I don't like the chat system. Sorry. Perhaps instead of trying to understand this off an answer, some comments and a chat, perhaps if you want to understand a set theoretic concept it would be good to actually study set theory. You can't possibly expect to understand a set theoretic answer (especially "an axiomatic answer") without understanding set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Alright then, no worries; thanks for taking the time to discuss it with me!

Comment: @thedoktar: Essentially, if you were going to write this out formally, it would violate some form of the rules governing existential quantifiers. What you do above is essentially instantiate a variable bound by an existential quantifier as a variable that's already free. Any good logic textbook will have examples of why this sort of thing leads to trouble.

Comment: I don't see that it has anything to do with circularity (or any axioms of set theory). This problem can be resolved by means of a purely logical argument. See my proof.

Answer (score 0):

User wrote:

> My question is: what about the Axiom of Separation (or the other axioms) precludes this construction?

It has nothing to do with any axioms of set theory (or circularity). This problem can be resolved with a purely logical argument.

**Theorem**

There do not exist sets $A$ and $S$ such that   $A = \{x \in S|x \not\in x\}$ and  $S = \{A, \varnothing\}$.

**Proof**

1. Suppose to the contrary that we do have sets $A$ and $S$ such that $\forall x:[x\in A \iff x \in S \land x\notin x]$
   and $S = \{A, \varnothing\}$.
2. From (1), $A\in A \iff A\in S \land A\notin A$
3. From (1), $A\in S$
4. From (2) and (3), we can obtain the contradiction $A\in A$ and $A\notin A$
5. Therefore, $\neg \exists A,S: [\forall x:[x\in A \iff x \in S \land x\notin x]\land S = \{A, \varnothing\}]$

**Note**

Similarly, we can prove that there do not exist sets $A$ and $S$ such that  $A = \{x \in S|x \not\in x\}$ and  $A\in S$.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was asking; you see, equally so, we could just say that the normal Russell's paradox set doesn't exist, but (from what I gather) axiomatic set theory was a way to develop axioms such that any set which could be constructed from the axioms was a valid set (ie didn't produce any contradictions). I didn't know about the axiom of regularity, which makes my construction not a set.

Comment: @thedoctar My point was that you don't necessarily need to cite any axioms of set theory to resolve this problem. Although you would have to change the notation, the above proof also works with '$\in$' as an arbitrary binary predicate in FOL.