# Axiom of Regularity allows for this set be an element of itself

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'm new to set theory, and the axiom of regularity has been giving me some trouble. It states that every non-empty set A has an element B such that A and B are disjoint sets. Apparently, this axiom implies that a set can't be an element of itself. I've heard (and agree with) arguments like this:

Let A be a set, and apply the axiom of regularity to {A}, which is a set by the axiom of pairing. We see that there must be an element of {A} which is disjoint from {A}. Since the only element of {A} is A, it must be that A is disjoint from {A}. So, since A ∈ {A}, we cannot have A ∈ A (by the definition of disjoint).

However, let's say there's a set A = {{1, 2}, A}. It seems like this set obeys the axiom of regularity, because {1, 2} is an element of A, and {1,2} and A are disjoint sets. However, the axiom of regularity shouldn't allow A to be an element of itself. I suppose there's a flaw in my logic somewhere, and I'm hoping someone knowledgeable can show me why this isn't allowed.

Comment: The axiom of regularity says that ***EVERY*** nonempty set is disjoint from one of its elements. Which of its elements is $\{A\}$ disjoint from?

Comment: Your alleged counterexample ignores the proof you write just one paragraph earlier. Was there anywhere in the proof that you required that $A=\{A\}$, or that $A$ has a specific form? No. Only that $A\in A$. Now, if indeed $A=\{\{1,2\},A\}$, then $A\in A$. The same proof still applies.

Comment: Some English-language authors (e.g. K. Kunen) call it Foundation, rather than Regularity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because a set appears to obey the axiom of regularity doesn't mean it actually is a set!  The axiom of regularity *restricts* what sets exist: if a non-empty set exists, then it has an element that is disjoint from it.  The axiom of regularity *doesn't* say that any putative collection which follows this rule has to actually exist as a set.

So, all you have observed is that if a set $A=\{\{1,2\},A\}$ existed, then $A$ would not be a counterexample to the axiom of regularity.  This in no way proves that such a set actually exists!  And in fact, if such a set did exist, then $\{A\}$ would be a counterexample to the axiom of regularity.  This is a contradiction, and therefore no such set $A$ exists.

Comment: Reminds me of the refuted & discarded "Axiom Schema of Abstraction" described in an intro to set theory by Suppes,    which is  the notion that there exists a set containing all & only those things having any stated property. (... cf Russell's Paradox).  We can have an axiom  $\exists A\;\forall x\;(x\in A\iff (x=\{1,2\}\lor x=A))$, or an axiom which implies that.... but we would then have to abandon Regularity.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Actually, even the refuted and discarded axiom schema of abstraction said that $\exists A\,\forall x\,(x\in A\iff\phi(x))$ when the variable $A$ is not free in the formula $\phi(x)$. Without that restriction on the variables in $\phi(x)$ there would be contradictions considerably more obvious than Russell's paradox.

Comment: Yes. I had forgotten that.

Answer (score 6):

You have learned the formal statement of the Axiom of Regularity, but you don't have a good picture of what it **means**. Let me try to explain it.

Let me call $A$ a **bottomless family of sets** if, for every set $x$ in $A,$ there is a set $y$ in $A$ such that $y\in x.$ A counterexample to the Axiom of Regularity is just a nonempty bottomless family of sets; in words, the Axiom of Regularity just says that no such family exists.

For example, suppose there is an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ of sets (not necessarily distinct) such that $a_{n+1}\in a_n$ for every $n,$ that is,
$$a_1\ni a_2\ni a_3\ni\dots\ni a_n\ni\dots\tag1$$
Then the set
$$A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$$
is bottomless (and of course nonempty); so the Axiom of Regularity says that the set $A,$ and therefore the sequence (1), can't exist.

Note that it is the set $A,$ and not (necessarily) any of the sets $a_n,$ which is a counterexample to Regularity.

Now suppose we had a "circle of sets", say
$$a_1\in a_2\in a_3\in a_4\in a_5\in a_1\tag2$$
In this case $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}$ is a nonempty bottomless family, contradicting regularity. Actually this is just a special case of (1) since we could write it as an infinite sequence:
$$a_5\ni a_4\ni a_3\ni a_2\ni a_1\ni a_5\ni a_4\ni a_3\ni a_2\ni a_1\ni a_5\ni a_4\ni\dots$$
In the very simplest case, the Axiom of Regularity tells us that no set can be an element of itself. Namely, if we had
$$a_1\in a_1\tag3$$
then (not $a_1$ but) the set $A=\{a_1\}$ would be a counterexample to Regularity.

In your example, assuming there is a set $a$ such that
$$a=\{\{1,2\},a\},\tag4$$
then we have $a\in a,$ and so the set $A=\{a\}$ is a counterexample to Regularity.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your argument lies right at the beginning:

> However, let's say there's a set $A = \{\{1, 2\}, A\}$.

You cannot actually *say* this in ZFC!  ZFC only allows one to construct sets -from already-existing sets-.  In order to construct $\{\{1, 2\}, A\}$, $A$ would already have to exist, either due to an axiom or due to a prior construction.  Therefore the result must be a new set different from $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: @PMar Welcome to MSE!  I've edited your post to use $\LaTeX$ formatting.  For an explanation of how this works, see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -1):

Let's check whether the candidate set $A=\{\{1,2\},A\}$ is a ZFC set. To qualify as such, it has to comply to all the ZFC axioms, including regularity/foundation (which determines whether a set is well-founded).

From the definition of the candidate set $A$, we infer that $A\supset \{A\}$. This means that every element of the latter is an element of the former. Thus, $A\in A$.

However, $A\in A$ violates the axiom of regularity/foundation, since it has been proven in the literature that [no well-founded set is an element of itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_set_is_an_element_of_itself).

Therefore, the candidate set A is not a well-founded set, which implies it is not a ZFC set. $\blacksquare$

---

Now, what was the flaw in the original poster's proof attempt?

It is made clear when we consider ZFC as an axiom *system*, not as a single axiom taken in isolation.

Let's look at the interaction between two axioms from ZFC.

The [axiom schema of specification/separation/restricted comprehension/subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) insures that every subset of a ZFC set is a ZFC set. That is, due to the axiom schema of specification, we are told that all the ZFC axioms automatically succeed all the way down (if ZFC is consistent).

But **the original (super)set must be a ZFC set for this insurance to be provided** by the axiom schema. Otherwise, no guarantees apply.

Thus, if you assume a candidate set is a ZFC set, then, when you take a look at its subsets, every subset must also be a ZFC set. Contrapositively, if at least one subset is not a ZFC set, then the superset is not a ZFC set either.

The subset$^{(a)}$ $\{A\}$ from the candidate set $A$ is not a ZFC set because $A \in A$ (which violates the axiom of regularity/foundation). The subset has the (super)set as an element. Thus, since the candidate set $A$ has a subset that does not comply to a ZFC axiom, then $A$ cannot be considered as a ZFC set, by the (contrapositive statement of the) axiom schema of specification.

If we had reasons to be assured that all the subsets of candidate set $A$ were ZFC sets, then the original poster's proof attempt would have worked. But *we were not assured this to begin with*. Indeed, the proof (above) showed that $A$ (which has a subset $\{A\}$) is not a ZFC set. A subset violated the axiom of regularity/foundation, thus, by the axiom schema of specification (in contrapositive form), $A$ is not a ZFC set.

Employing the axiom of regularity/foundation to prove whether a candidate set complies to it is not the most common use case; more often, we employ this axiom as an additional fact/premise to obtain an interesting consequence from sets *we already know to be ZFC sets*. For instance, if $b$ and $c$ are ZFC sets **and** $b\in c$, then, by applying the axiom of pairing and the axiom of regularity/foundation as additional facts, we have the tools we need in order to prove that $c\notin b$.

$_{(a)}$ Obtained by the implicit application of the axiom schema of specification in the proof above.

Answer (score -2):

I'm actually not very familiar with set theory, but I think I see the issue here: when working with set theory, you adopt a certain definition of "set", which entails some mathematical rules (including the axiom of regularity) that any object has to satisfy in order to be a set. An object $A$ which satisfies $A = \{\{1,2\}, A\}$ may "exist" (whatever that means), but it does not satisfy the rules of "set-hood", and therefore is not a set. Just because the notation you use to define it *looks* set-like, that doesn't make it a set.

I could probably make a rough analogy to the "number" $0.00\ldots1$, which is written using basically the same notation as many things which are numbers, but does not actually satisfy the rules of "number-hood".

You might also find it useful to read [Define $A = \{ 1,2,A \}$, $A$ can not be a set (Axiom of regularity). Can $A$ be a "class" or a "collection" of elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933720/define-a-1-2-a-a-can-not-be-a-set-axiom-of-regularity-can-a-be?rq=1), e.g. Asaf Karagila's answer which points out that the definition $A = \{\{1,2\}, A\}$ is circular. Depending on your frame of mind that might make more sense than what I've said above.

Comment: Good point. I think my error was that in order for a set to "exist", it has to be constructible from the axioms. i.e. given that a set exists (which according to Wikipedia is fundamental to first-order logic), such as the empty set, the axioms say that other sets made out of that set exist. I guess the axioms make it impossible to prove that a set like A={{1,2},A} exists, so it might as well not.

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable. Starting from the empty set, you can't create a set satisfying your condition for much the same reason you can't create a natural number $x$ satisfying $x = x + 1$ by starting from $0$. (Though I would caution against jumping from "I can't construct this thing" to "this thing doesn't exist" in general.)

Comment: This is not the issue.